# Mongoose: Why isn't populate() working for my self-referencing model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

As far as I can tell, populate() is being called in my code (because I get an error if I give it a wrong path), but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

I searched for past question in Stack Overflow, and I've not seen one where someone's using a model that's referencing itself, so my guess is that that might be the problem.

This [Mongoose doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) is where I'm reading up on how to use `populate()`.

### My Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String },
    email: { type: String, unique: true },
    teamLeaders: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Agent' }],
    teamMembers: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Agent' }]
});

let Agent = mongoose.model('Agent', schema);
Agent.init();

module.exports = Agent;
```

### The actual document in MongoDB Atlas (anonymised name + email)

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62e3e0ab57560a5c15a535e0"
  },
  "teamLeaders": [],
  "teamMembers": [
    {
      "$oid": "62e3f548678dbed5593acc8e"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "62e3f548678dbed5593acc91"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "62e3f548678dbed5593acc94"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "62e3f548678dbed5593acc97"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "62e3f548678dbed5593acc9a"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "62e3f548678dbed5593acc9d"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "62e3f548678dbed5593acca0"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "62e3f548678dbed5593acca3"
    }
  ],
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Smith",
  "email": "john@smith.com",
  "__v": 8
}
```

### Code where I'm calling populate()

```
const Agent = require('../models/agents');

const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const db = require("../config/db");
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || db.url);

// I've removed other functions that are not related to this. And the DB connection is definitely working fine.

// Actual private function in my code.
async function addAgent(firstName, lastName, email, isTeamLeader, teamLeader) {
    let newAgent = Agent();

    newAgent.firstName = firstName;
    newAgent.lastName = lastName;
    newAgent.email = email;

    if (isTeamLeader) {
        await newAgent.save();
    } else {
        newAgent.teamLeaders.push(teamLeader);

        let savedAgent = await newAgent.save();

        teamLeader.teamMembers.push(savedAgent);
        await teamLeader.save();
    }
}

// This is a dummy function to show how I created the agents.
async function createAgents() {
    await addAgent('John', 'Smith', 'john@smith.com', true, null);

    // Some time later... I called addAgent() manually since this is for an internal team with only 30 people.
    // It's also why I'm just querying for the firstName since there's only one John in the internal team.
    let teamLeader = await Agent.findOne({ firstName: 'John' });
    await addAgent('Peter', 'Parker', 'peter@parker.com', false, teamLeader);
}

// This is the main one where I try to call populate().
async function mainFunction() {
    Agent.findOne({ firstName: 'John' }).populate({ path: 'teamMembers', model: 'Agent' }).exec((err, agent) => {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        console.log('Populated agent: ' + agent);
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you check if you have multiple documents with `firstName: Sam`? `findOne` will return the first match it finds.

Comment: @NeNaD Yup, just double-checked and I definitely only have one in the database. I also attached a debugger to check the `findOne` result and it's a perfect match for the one I'm looking at in the DB, including the object ID.

Comment: What do you mean by "but it doesn't seem to be doing anything.". What is the result of your `console.log()` ? Which version of Mongoose are you using ?

Comment: @Weedoze I'm on Mongoose 6.3.8.

The code doesn't even reach `console.log()`, which confuses me. Like it doesn't even seem to reach the `exec()` part, but `findOne()` is definitely running and returning the correct result. So it feels like `populate()` isn't even being called, but I tried giving it a wrong path and it does throw an error.

Comment: After the result of `findOne()` can you please check if this is true `agent.teamMembers[0] instanceof ObjectId;` ?
And then try `Agent.findOne({ firstName: 'John' }).populate('teamMembers').exec(....)`

Comment: `Agent.findOne({ firstName: 'John' }).populate('teamMembers').exec(....)` gives me the same result, in that it never reaches the `exec()` part.

I think you're onto something with the `instanceof` question though. With `let agent = await Agent.findOne({ firstName: 'Sam' });` and `console.log(agent.teamMembers[0] instanceof mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId);`, I'm getting a false (which wasn't what I expected). I'm guessing you know the reason?

Comment: @jon2512chua I don't know the reason yet but it can be the source of the problem. The issue seems to be that when using `populate` mongoose doesn't recognize your array as an array of `ObjectID`. Can you show me how you add those objetcs in you array and save them ?      + Can you please ping my username so I can receive a notification ?

Comment: @Weedoze Thanks mate! I added the code to the "Code where I'm calling populate()" section in my question. The part you asked for is in `createAgents()`.

Comment: Thanks for addding this info. Can you try to use the ID of the saved agent instead of the object itself ? `teamLeader.teamMembers.push(savedAgent.id);`

Comment: @Weedoze So sorry for the late reply - missed your response notification! I tried what you suggested, using both `savedAgent.id` and `savedAgent._id`, but they give the same results.

Comment: @Weedoze **However**, I just realised the problems:
1. I completely misunderstood the docs on what `populate()` does. I thought that it'd update the actual document with the populated result, but all it does is that it does a 2nd query so I can access the child's properties at runtime.
2. `populate()` is doing its thing, but for some reason, the callback in `exec()` isn't working. If I remove the callback (ie only use `exec()`) and just await the Promise, then it's all fine. Just using `populate()` or even `then(callback)` works fine too. Weird!

Comment: @jon2512chua: Great - Please post your answer and mark it as the answer of your question for the future viewers

Comment: @Weedoze Thanks for the reminder! Will do that now. Btw, do let me know if you know why `exec(callback)` doesn't get called - it's a headscratcher for sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to questions/prompt from @Weedoze, I've figured out where the issues lie.

There are two main problems.

### Problem 1

I had completely misunderstood the [Mongoose docs for populate()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

My initial understanding was that calling `populate()` will update the actual MongoDB document with the populated result. However, what it does is that it's a quality-of-life/convenience feature where it does a second query to replace the reference with the actual document contents. **All of these only exist/happen at runtime.**

### Problem 2

`populate()` is doing its thing here, the problem is that the callback in `exec()` isn't actually running - I'm still pretty stumped by this as I can't see a reason why it wouldn't work, and I'm doing the same thing as the doc (as well as other guides on the internet).

To clarify, this means that the `populate()` function does run, but the callback function inside `exec()` isn't being reached at all (I've checked by blocking it with a debugger checkpoint).

**Ways I'm using the callback which do not work.**

```
Agent.findOne({ firstName: 'John' }).populate('teamMembers').exec((err, agent) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('Populated agent: ' + agent);
});
```

```
Agent.findOne({ firstName: 'John' }).populate('teamMembers').exec(function(err, agent) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('Populated agent: ' + agent);
});
```

**To get around this, I just access the results in other ways, e.g.**

```
let agent = await Agent.findOne({ firstName: 'John' }).populate('teamMembers');
console.log('Populated agent: ' + agent);
```

```
// Pretty much same thing as above. Only difference is that exec() returns a proper Promise.
// Tried this mostly to confirm that exec() does run and the issue is with the callback.
let agent = await Agent.findOne({ firstName: 'John' }).populate('teamMembers').exec();
console.log('Populated agent: ' + agent);
```

```
// Since populate() returns a "then-able" result anyway.
Agent.findOne({ firstName: 'John' }).populate('teamMembers').then((err, agent) => {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    console.log('Populated agent: ' + agent);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The data you got does bot correspond to the data you have. How dhould mongoose know that the reference id is inside `oid`?

With

```
teamLeaders: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Agent' }],
```

one should expect inside atlas something like

```
"teamLeaders": [
    ObjectId("62e3f548678dbed5593acca0"),
    ObjectId("62e3f548678dbed5593acca3"),
    ...
  ],
```

Make sure the ref is exactly referencing the correct value.

Anyway I'd use an aggregation, as it is probably way more efficientand can be used also with mongoose if you have to

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/

Comment: Isn't `"$oid": "62e3f548678dbed5593acc8e"` just another way that Mongo shows `ObjectId("62e3f548678dbed5593acc8e")`, ie should be the same thing?

Comment: I just checked the document, and they're both definitely the same thing. I'm using MongoDB Compass to view my documents, and the JSON view shows `oid`, but table and list view shows `ObjectId`.

Comment: No it's not the same, I assumed you posted the bson document, not an (unofficial) json version. Can you please post the bson document?

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but are you asking for the actual binary BSON file? Like the one you get when doing a mongodump, and is pretty much unreadable when opened in a text editor?

Also, for reference, the JSON was the direct copy result from MongoDB Compass.